# How can I tell if wireless numpad not working is hardware issue or Windows 10 issue?

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, numpad

I just bought a wireless numpad from Amazon, and putting batteries into the pad, putting the usb receiver in my laptop, and then turning the switch on for the pad, it doesn't work.

The device is recognised as a 2.4G Wireless Mouse and Keyboard.

How can I check where the issue is? Are there drivers I could install to fix this? Or is it a dud/fake/mismatched Amazon offbrand item?

Comment: Are you sure you got a good battery? Is it the right way around? USB recognized by the computer is good. Is there any indicator on the numpad that it is on? Any led? If it lit up, and USB is recognized, but still no go - your best bet is go back to the seller, and ask for support / replacement / refund.

Comment: Yeah I tried all the ones in my remotes. I don't know how to tell if it's on, but it's got lights for NumLock button. I'll have to send it back to Amazon then and just look more better website. Thanks